# duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed Error while opening a csv file

Tags: csv

I have a very big `csv` file and would like to set the first column as row names and then remove the first column. to do I simply used this code:

```
test <- read.delim(file = "BM062B_AP_2.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",", row.names=1)
```

but keep getting this error:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

do you know how to fix it?